# In PhpRedisConnector.php line 161 Connection refused redis laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, redis

I need help setting up Redis correctly in Laravel. I've already tried what I found on the internet, but I'm not sure if I'm missing a step. I'm getting the following error:

```
In PhpRedisConnector.php line 161:

  Connection refused
```

I installed the Redis extension for PHP, I think i can confirm it with this:

```
$ php -m | grep redis
redis
```

Then I installed Docker and Redis, and I received the PONG from the PING.

```
$ docker exec -it local-redis redis-cli
127.0.01:6379> ping
PONG
```

Also, I have restarted FPM With

```
sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm.service
```

After that, I cleared the Laravel cache.

```
$ php artisan optimize:clear
```

And I configured the .env with the following.

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

And i try to execute this artisan command and i get the error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class TestRedisCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'custom:test_redis';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $redis = Redis::connection();
        if ($redis->ping()) {
            echo "Conexión Exitosa";
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Please, is there something I'm missing? I don't see where the error could be.

Comment: How are you creating the containers?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with your __program__, and not with your system and/or network __configuration__?  If the latter, then Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask (maybe [sf] would be appropriate, but check their help centre first).

Comment: @TeemuRisikko
I use 
``sudo docker pull redis,
 sudo docker run --name local-redis -d redis,
 sudo docker start local-redis
``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have,  `Connection refused`, is one of the clearest indications in situations like these of what's happening. Aside from firewalls and stuff, the only real option is that *there is no redis running in that port*.

Your test of `docker exec -it local-redis redis-cli` -> `ping` does literally nothing to confirm your problem, because what you are doing with `docker exec` is connect to the inside of the container and test there, whereas your application seems to be running locally on the host machine, as indicated by your env variables:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

then the port needs to be [*published*](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports) outside of the container. They are not open by default and by design.

You said you are connecting like this:

```
docker run --name local-redis -d redis
```

You need to change this to:

```
docker run --name local-redis -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d redis
```